# wordpress plugin - how to count home page visitors

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I am working on wordpress plugin, need to add home page counter, how can I do that ? I don't want other users to put code on home page or their posts. My plugin should do all the job.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want the hit counter to be visible [circa 1990?](http://8.mshcdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/Evolutionweb-full1.jpg). You could use one of those [cgi hit counters](http://www.riverdrift.com/m2/hitgenerator.shtml) and create a function that hooks into `wp_footer()`

Comment: by using `wp_footer()`, how can I find post id for the displayed page ? Thanks, you comment is helpful.